# In Dynamics is it possible to report on the change in deal size?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I create a weekly report on sales opportunities and am being asked to report on changes (e.g. change in deal size, new deals, closed deals), specifically looking at the biggest changes.

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new SalesChangeHistory entity that gets populated whenever a Sales Opportunity changes via a plugin.  It could include flags that specify if the change was a change in size, brand new, or closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't want to develop new entities and plugins you could turn on auditing and create an SSRS report against the audit data. The data isn't in the best format but it's achievable! (just!)

Having said this the "best" solution would be as Daryl has suggested.